How to Set Up and Test Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) Push Notifications with HTTP v1 API Using Postman?
I am trying to set up and test push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with the new HTTP v1 API via Postman. I need to generate an OAuth 2.0 token to authenticate my requests and send a push notification to a specific device. I have the FCM service account JSON and the device token. Could someone guide me through the process of setting this up in Postman, including how to generate the OAuth 2.0 token and format the request?
Here are the details I have:

Service account JSON file from Firebase
Device token for the target device
Postman for executing HTTP requests

What are the steps to generate the OAuth 2.0 token using Python and set up the Postman request to send a push notification using FCM's HTTP v1 API?

I believe this might be helpful to other developers. I will try to break down the steps as easily as possible.
Step 1 - Download the Firebase Private Key
Firebase Console => Project Setting => Service Accounts => Generate new private key

Step 2 - Generate OAuth 2.0 Token using FCM service account credentials. You can you thie Python to genrate it
  import json
  import jwt
  import time
  import requests  # This requires the `requests` library

  # Load the service account key JSON file
  with open('path_to_your_service_account.json', 'r') as f:
      service_account = json.load(f)

  # Define the JWT payload
  payload = {
      'iss': service_account['client_email'],
      'sub': service_account['client_email'],
      'aud': 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
      'iat': int(time.time()),
      'exp': int(time.time()) + 3600,
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'
  }

  # Encode the JWT
  encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(payload, service_account['private_key'], algorithm='RS256')

  # Request an OAuth 2.0 token
  response = requests.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', data={
      'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      'assertion': encoded_jwt
  })

  oauth2_token = response.json()['access_token']
  print(oauth2_token)

If you get this error:

Algorithm 'RS256' could not be found. Do you have cryptography installed

make sure to run pip install cryptography this will install cryptography package to your machine.
Or this error:

JWT: 'module' object has no attribute 'encode'

Refer to this answer
The print statment will have a format of ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA this is the Oauth 2.0 token.
Step 3 - Postman configration, plug in the token you have found insde the postman config

you can get your project id from the url of the firebase project
Method: POST
URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/messages:send
Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {oauth2_token}

Notification body
  "message": {
    "token": "DEVICE_REGISTRATION_TOKEN",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Test Notification",
      "body": "This is a test message from Postman."
    }
  }
}


You can simply use "Firebase Cloud Messaging API" auth type in postman, which will be automatically available for you when you fill in the URL for the FCM request.

In your Flutter project create a new file and add this code:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_admin_sdk/firebase_admin_sdk.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<String> getOAuthToken() async {
  final serviceAccount = ServiceAccount.fromJson(
    json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('path/to/service-account.json')),
  );
  final credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromServiceAccount(serviceAccount);
  final accessToken = await credentials.tokenInfo.accessToken;
  return accessToken.toString();
}

Replace 'path/to/service-account.json' with the actual path to your Firebase service account JSON file.
Call the getOAuthToken() function to get the OAuth 2.0 access token.
Create a new request in Postman and set the request type to "POST".
In the request URL, enter: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/messages:send
Replace {YOUR_PROJECT_ID} with your Firebase project ID, which you can find in the Firebase console.
In the "Headers" tab, add the following key-value pairs:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}
Replace {YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN} with the access token you generated in the previous step.
In the "Body" tab, select "raw" and "JSON" as the data type.Then enter the following JSON payload:
{
  "message": {
    "token": "{DEVICE_TOKEN}",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Test Notification",
      "body": "This is a test push notification."
    }
  }
}

Replace {DEVICE_TOKEN} with the device token you have for the target device.
Click the "Send" button in Postman to execute the request and send the push notification.
You should see a response from the FCM API indicating whether the push notification was successfully delivered.
Here's the complete Flutter code to generate the OAuth 2.0 access token and send the push notification:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_admin_sdk/firebase_admin_sdk.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> sendPushNotification() async {
  final accessToken = await getOAuthToken();

  final url = Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/messages:send');
  final headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
  };
  final body = jsonEncode({
    'message': {
      'token': '{DEVICE_TOKEN}',
      'notification': {
        'title': 'Test Notification',
        'body': 'This is a test push notification.',
      },
    },
  });

  final response = await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print('Push notification sent successfully');
  } else {
    print('Failed to send push notification: ${response.statusCode} - ${response.body}');
  }
}

Future<String> getOAuthToken() async {
  final serviceAccount = ServiceAccount.fromJson(
    json.decode(await rootBundle.loadString('path/to/service-account.json')),
  );
  final credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromServiceAccount(serviceAccount);
  final accessToken = await credentials.tokenInfo.accessToken;
  return accessToken.toString();
}

Remember to replace the following placeholders:
{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}: Your Firebase project ID
{DEVICE_TOKEN}: The device token for the target device
'path/to/service-account.json': The actual path to your Firebase service account JSON file

Download the Firebase Private Key from Firebase Console :
Firebase Console => Project Setting => Service Accounts => Generate new private key and download the file.
In Flutter Project:
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:dart_jsonwebtoken/dart_jsonwebtoken.dart';

getOAuthToken() async {
final int iat = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
final int exp = iat + 3600;
final jwt = JWT(
    {
      'iss': 'client_email', // copy value from downloaded json file
      'sub': 'client_email', // copy value from downloaded json file
      'aud': 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
      'iat': iat,
      'exp': exp,
      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging',
    },
  );
var privateKey = 'privateKey'; // copy value from downloaded json file
final token = jwt.sign(RSAPrivateKey(privateKey),algorithm: JWTAlgorithm.RS256);

final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'),
    body: {
      'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
      'assertion': token,
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final oauth2Token = json.decode(response.body)['access_token'];
    print('OAuth2 Token: $oauth2Token');
  } else {
    print('Failed to get OAuth2 token. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response: ${response.body}');
  }
}

Postman :
Method: POST
URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/messages:send
Headers:
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {oauth2Token}

Notification Data:
{"message": {
    "token": "DEVICE_REGISTRATION_TOKEN",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Test Notification",
      "body": "This is a test message from Postman."
    },
"data": {
        
        }
  }
} 

Flutter Package Used :
dart_jsonwebtoken

I've been trying to send a push notification through Postman for two days, but for some reason, it hasn't worked. Then I came across the Google OAuth Playground which offers tools to send push notifications via HTTP requests. I wrote a guide on Medium to help others set up the playground and get it working for push notifications.
